# Is there any proof of Galilean Transformation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Is there any proof of Galilean Transformation? Is it proved from experiment, theory or it simply is an axiom?

Answer (score 2):

The [Galilean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) is not proven from experiment.  The Galilean transformation should be used only when two frames of reference are moving at a constant speed (possibly zero) relative to each other.  But even with that limitation there is experimental evidence that it is incorrect and that the [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) should be preferred.

All that said, the error in using the Galilean transformation for many every-day physical problems is small enough that it can often be ignored.

Here is a useful primer on the subject:

https://www.ck12.org/book/ck-12-physics---intermediate/section/22.1/

Comment: If Galilean transformation cannot be proven from the experiment, how can you justify the statement that "there is experimental evidence that it is incorrect and that the Lorentz transformation should be preferred." ? I think your answer needs some clarification about this point.

Comment: @GiorgioP.  I did not say it cannot be proven.  I said it is not proven.  In fact, it is disproved (for relative speeds not equal to zero).

Comment: @Tony could you clarify how your terminology of "not proven" is different from "cannot be proven"?

Comment: @SongofPhysics.  "is not proven from experiment" means "we haven't proved it".  "Cannot be proven" means "we could never prove it".  Perhaps it would have been clearer, especially for speakers of other languages, if I had said: "The Galilean transformation has not been proven by experiment" (because it has been disproven by experiment).

Comment: @Tony for starters a *transformation* is not a *proposition* that requires proof. It need only be well-defined. Most good modern texts on classical dynamics make the domain of validity (as an idealisation) quite clear early-on. So the transformation is well defined and applicable within that domain. Furthermore, it is a *model* based on actual observations made my Gallileo and Newton and can thus be said to be *constructed* from experiment. As originally devised, it may be alright to say that the transformations aren't universally valid though, but that's incorrect in modern usage.

Comment: @SongofPhysics.  I answered your question on terminology.  As for the rest, I'm happy with my answer and will leave semantics to others.

Answer (score 2):

A Galilean transformation $G(R, \vec{v}, \vec{a}, s)$ can be uniquely expressed as a composition of -

- Translations: $(\vec{x}, t) \longmapsto (\vec{x} + \vec{a}, t + s),$
- Rotations: $(\vec{x}, t) \longmapsto (R\vec{x}, t),$
- Uniform Motion of Spacetime: $(\vec{x}, t) \longmapsto (\vec{x} + \vec{v}t, t),$

where, a point in spacetime is given by the ordered pair $(\vec{x}, t)$ with $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $R:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is an orthogonal transformation. In particular, $R \in SO(3)$. One can prove that the set of all such transformations forms what is known as a *group* in mathematics. One can also show that the *Galilean group* is the group of *motions* of *Galilean relativity*, which stems from the Newtonian picture of absolute space and time which is physically valid only for $v = |\vec{v}| \ll c$, where $c$ is the speed of light.

One can indeed recover this Galilean group from the group of motions of special relativity (Poincaré group) under this limit via group contraction. The conceptual and empirical basis for Galilean transformations have been discussed at length by Galileo and in particular Newton in his *Principia*. Mathematically, the Galilean transformations simply embody the intuitive notion of addition and subtraction of velocities as vectors.

As far as the aforementioned proofs are concerned, I invite you to try writing them down :)

Comment: I disagree with the statement that "the Galilean transformations simply embody the intuitive notion of addition and subtraction of velocities as vectors." Implicitly you are identifying vectors belonging to different vector spaces without any proof. In general, the sum of vectors in one vector space can't be extended to the sum of vectors of different vector spaces.

Comment: @GiorgioP I do not believe that requires any proof per say (given that there is a well defined way to add vector spaces) but could you perhaps elaborate in case I'm missing the point?